# Alamofire Router that returns POST request

Tags: ios, swift, post, alamofire

after reading **[RAYWENDERLICH Alamofire tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/85080/beginning-alamofire-tutorial#comments)** I decided to build own router, It works fine except a little detail. It returns `GET` requests but I need `POST` request in my case. I spend some time trying to set `HTTPMethod = "POST"` in Router but probably because of lack of experience I was doing it wrong and getting some errors. So what exactly do I need to change in router to make it return `POST` requests?

Her is my code

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible
{
    static let baseURLString = "http://www.com"
    case Friends(Int)
    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest
    {
        let (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {
            switch self
            {
            case .Friends (let ID):
                let params = ["userID": "\(ID)"]
                return ("/getFriends.php", params) 
            }
        }()
        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything looks good to me, try renaming  let URLRequest to something else (resultRequest etc..) since you already have a variable called URLRequest on the outer scope, you must also add the line resultRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

Comment: Edit the post and enter the link of the tutorial where I bold the text so it is easier to people understand what you are trying.

Comment: @Kaan Dedeoglu I tried to add URLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
right after let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path)) but it gives me the following error "cannot assign to 'HTTPMethod' in 'URLRequest' "

Comment: Use a NSMutableURLRequest instead of NSURLRequest

Comment: @Kaan Dedeoglu Thanks a lot, problem is solved, I knew that it has a simple solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code perfectly :) Thanks @Kaan Dedeoglu

```
  enum Router: URLRequestConvertible
  {
    static let baseURLString = "http://www.com"
    case Friends(Int)
    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest
      {
        let (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {
          switch self
          {
          case .Friends (let ID):
            let params = ["userID": "\(ID)"]
            return ("/getFriends.php", params)
          }
          }()
        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        URLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    }
  }
```

Comment: @ iMemon I've already figured it out, anyway Thanks for good answer

Answer (score 2):

**simple solution** with **swift 3+** and **Alamofire 4+**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public enum mRouter: URLRequestConvertible {
  static let baseURLString = "baseURL"
  static let token = "token"

  case profile
  case timeline

  public func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    var method: HTTPMethod {
      switch self {
      case .profile:
        return .get
      case .timeline:
        return .post
      }
    }

    let params: ([String: Any]?) = {
      switch self {
      case .profile(let Id):
        return (["id": Id])
      case .timeline:
        return nil
      }
    }()

    let url: URL = {
      let relativePath: String?
      switch self {
      case .profile:
        relativePath = "profile"
      case .timeline:
        relativePath = "timeline"
      }
      var url = URL(string: mRouter.baseURLString)!
      if let relativePath = relativePath {
        url = url.appendingPathComponent(relativePath)
      }
      return url
    }()

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
    urlRequest.setValue(mRouter.token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let encoding = JSONEncoding.default
    return try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: params)
  }
}
```